# Auto login with certain parameter in itunes application link

Tags: ios, iphone, url, itunes

I have certain requirement that asks for sending a person invitation with download URL of the app from the itunes and pass the login parameters like username and password with appending to that link then when someone downloads the app from that url i need to identify those parameter and auto login that user with those parameters..

need some guidance to this to get this to work if any help or guidance will appreciate a lot..
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to send a download URL to someone which would open iTunes to an app Page, download that app then also auto login with their iTunes credentials? If so, there is no way you are going to able to do this in any sort of legitimate way.

Comment: @CW0007007 :- No i mean to send custom parameter like username and password with the download link so user can download the application from that link and based on that i can use those parameters and auto login that user with those parameters...if you have any suggestions please help